# Loading a textfile array with Numpy and converting to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, text-files

Im having a rather basic issue that has been giving me difficulty. I wish to convert the data I have in this text file into a numpy array. I have tried using the loadtxt function but have been having issues configuring it properly. The data comes in a series of chunks as such (see example). I wish to convert each chunk that's in side the square brackets into a separate numpy array.

This will eventually turn into part of a live feed where a data packet as such is sent every second but for now im just trying to figure out how to get numpy to read textfiles.

Much appreciated

```
[23.75, 24.50, 26.25, 24.25, 22.25, 21.25, 21.50, 24.50, 
20.75, 20.75, 22.75, 22.25, 20.50, 20.50, 21.75, 24.25, 
20.75, 20.75, 20.75, 20.00, 20.50, 21.00, 21.75, 23.00, 
20.75, 21.00, 21.50, 22.50, 21.25, 20.75, 21.25, 23.50, 
23.75, 25.75, 23.50, 21.25, 20.75, 20.50, 21.00, 22.75, 
23.75, 24.25, 22.50, 20.50, 20.75, 20.75, 21.75, 23.00, 
23.25, 21.75, 20.50, 20.00, 21.00, 20.50, 21.50, 23.50, 
21.25, 20.50, 21.00, 20.75, 20.25, 21.00, 22.00, 25.00, 
]
```

Comment: I personally use the [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function and convert to the resulting Dataframe to a numpy array for this type of problem.

Comment: This is not a convenient format to read in. Unless you desperately want to spend time on this, consider changing the input format if it's for testing. E.g. separate CSV files; or just npy files directly

Comment: @MikaelÖhman I agree but unfortunately, the data is coming from an Arduino-enabled thermal imaging camera. The data it reports is a series of 8x8 pixel temperature readings there is no way to alter the data. Once read  I run a bicubic interpolation to expand it to a 100x100 pixel image and output the data as a heat map which generates a thermal image.

Comment: Nothing or what you wrote in this comment addresses the reason why this completely non-standard inconvenient file format had to be used, which is the actual issue here. Where the data comes from or what processing has or will take place doesn't make any difference.
Your question even indicates this is just temporarily reading test data from disk, and that the real application will get the real data directly. The doubt the camera is writing this horrendous file format you've got here.

Answer (score 0):

As Mikael said above, this is not a convenient way to store data in text file. If you want to read directly using numpy, then it would be better to save it as .npy file or .csv file. If you still wants to read from plain text file, then you have to read the file as text data initially, then have to convert into numpy data as bellow. Hope it helps.

```
import numpy as np

with open('data.txt', 'r') as fp:
    data = fp.read()

np_array = np.array(data)
```